# Consuming data from webservice with vb.net

Tags: html, xml, vb.net, xhtml

Im doing a webform in vb.net I'm consuming a [webservice](http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx/GetCountries), Which returns me to all the countries

Only have 1 button <kbd>Enviar</kbd> that calls the countries.

```vb
Imports service_country = WebServiceVB2.country

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim serv_country As New service_country.country '--Create object'
        Dim MyDoc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
        Dim MyXml As String = serv_country.GetCountries() '--Execute procedure from webservice'

        MyDoc.LoadXml(MyXml) '--Read Myxml and convert to XML'
        Dim SymbolText As String = MyDoc.SelectSingleNode("//NewDataSet/Table/Name").InnerText '--select the node'
        Label1.Text = SymbolText

    End Sub
```

**My question is** How can I select all the values that are inside the 'name'.
Actually it only shows one. 
For Example:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like `Dim oNode1 As Xml.XmlNodeList = MyDoc.SelectNodes("//NewDataSet/Table/Name")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an interesting problem.  Since data is coming as a webpage the open bracket was coming as "& l t ;" while the closing bracket was coming as "& g t ;".  So these had to be replaced.  I used xml linq to get the names :

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq

Module Module1
    Const URL As String = "http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx/GetCountries"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc1 As XDocument = XDocument.Load(URL)

        Dim docStr As String = doc1.ToString()
        docStr = docStr.Replace("&gt;", ">")
        docStr = docStr.Replace("&lt;", "<")

        Dim doc2 As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(docStr)

        Dim root As XElement = doc2.Root
        Dim defaultNs As XNamespace = root.GetDefaultNamespace()
        Dim names() As String = doc2.Descendants(defaultNs + "Name").Select(Function(x) CType(x, String)).ToArray()
    End Sub
End Module
```

---

Using WebUtility

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Net


Module Module1
    Const URL As String = "http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx/GetCountries"
    Sub Main()

        Dim xReader As XmlReader = XmlTextReader.Create(URL)
        xReader.MoveToContent()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(WebUtility.HtmlDecode("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""iso-8859-9"" ?>" & xReader.ReadOuterXml))

        Dim root As XElement = doc.Root
        Dim defaultNs As XNamespace = root.GetDefaultNamespace()
        Dim names() As String = doc.Descendants(defaultNs + "Name").Select(Function(x) CType(x, String)).ToArray()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Thanks, I just added `For Each` for read the content. It was very helpful.